# Notation in "proof sketch" of the Banach Tarski paradox on wikipedia

Tags: notation, paradoxes

I'm trying to understand the proof sketch [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Tarski_paradox#A_sketch_of_the_proof). In [step 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Tarski_paradox#Step_3) of the proof sketch we have $A_{1} = S(a)M \cup M \cup B$. My understanding is that $S(a)$ and $M$ are both sets. I have failed to understand what is meant by "$S(a)M$". Can anyone shed light upon this?

Comment: Above of Step 2 you can find *The notation $aS(a^{-1})$ means take all the strings in $S(a^{-1})$ and concatenate them on the left with $a$.* So I believe that you can do this for $M$.

Answer (score 1):

$S(a)$ is a certain set of maps on the unit sphere, $M$ is a subset of the unit sphere, thus it makes sense to define $S(a)M := \{s(x) | s\in S(a), x\in M\}$ i.e. as the image of every point in $M$ under every map in $S(a)$.